# Class change based on local time : local sunrise/sunset calculation?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and put together this code to change the background on my page based on visitors local time.

I can't really test it yet, so first question would be, is this actually working? :D

And the main question: is there a way to set the sunrise and sunset times (set to 6 and 20 now) to follow the actual local times of the visitor?

Any help very much appreciated!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(change_background, 1000 * 60 * 60);

    function change_background() {
      var d = new Date();
      var n = d.getHours();
      console.log(n);
      
      
      if (n == 6 || n == 20) {
      
      document.getElementById("intro").className = "inter";
      } else {
      
      
      if (n == 23 || n < 7) {
      
      document.getElementById("intro").className = "night";
      } else {
      document.getElementById("intro").className = "day";
      }
      console.log("test");
      
    }
       
      console.log("test");
    }
    
    
    change_background();
  </script>
```

Comment: Considering there's an html element by id `intro` and there are css classes named `inter` , `night` and `day` in your code, this should work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this shorter and reordered code – main difference is we set the class each time the function is called, your code would not have done anything after hour 7, execpt in exactly the hours 6, 20 and 23.

```
function change_background() {
  var nowHour = new Date().getHours();
  document.querySelector("#intro").className = ( nowHour >= 6 && nowHour <= 20 ) ? "inter" : ( (nowHour >= 23 || nowHour <= 5) ? "night" : "day" );
}

setInterval(change_background, 1000 * 60 * 60); change_background(); // trigger interval and first check
```

To use the local timezone you can use [getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) – but things can become nightmarish with timezones, if you want to be as near to accurate as you can get. Just think about a science station in the polar regions, sunrise and sunset lose their meaning in such extreme scenarios. But with the offset you can use that to link it to a known good sunrise time .. but then you need to edit your file every day (or at least couple of days) to match the progression throughout the year.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

So this calculates offset from UTC?

But then apparently I already have the local time, I wonder if there's a way to calculate sunrise and sunset from that, using the date for example? 

The original script is in 1 hour intervals only, so it wouldn't have to be very precise. The idea is that there's one background image during the night, one during the day, and when they switch (around real world sunrise/sunset) there's a third image.

Sorry if it's a newbie problem!

Comment: Your original code has issues, those I fixed; the idea of switching style depending on time comes with a lot of problems if you want to do it "perfectly". If you decide it is enough to say "sunrise is at 6 o'clock every day of the year" then the given code already does that, since "getHours()" is in local time already – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours